# Getting a single User Picture from sql DB (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

So I'm in the middle of creating an E-Commerce site for a class. On my Profile page I'm planning to display various info stored in the db. Right now I'm only messing with the user photo. I have a function in the model that gets the Users photo from the column 'Image_Path' in DB 'users'. My problem is that for each profile view it shows the same photo. I think its return the whole array of pictures and maybe just sets it as the first one?

here is the model

```
<?php
class Profile_Model extends CI_Model
{

    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->load->database();
    }

 //    public function get_profile_picture()
 //    {
 //
 //      $query = $this->db->get('users');
 //      return $query -> result();
 // }
 public function get_single_profile($id){
   //get whole table

   $this->db->select('Username');
   $this->db->select('Image_Path');
   $this->db->from('users');
   $this->db->where('User_ID', $id);
   $query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();

 }//end get_single_profile

 //for uploading profile pics
public function set_profile_pic(){

}

 }//CLASS
?>
```

The Controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Profile extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('session');    //needed to use global session variables
        $this->load->helper('language');
        $this->load->model('Profile/Profile_Model');
}

public function index()
{

    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {

        $data['profilepicture'] = $this->Profile_Model->get_single_profile();

            $this->load->view('Profile/Profile', $data);
    }// echo session variable logged_in
    else{

        redirect( base_url().'Login');  //redirect to user profile view after verification)
    }
}//END Index
public function logout(){
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect(base_url(). 'Login');
}//END LOGOUT

public function display_profile_pic(){

    $data['profilepicture'] = $this->Profile_Model->get_profile_picture();
    $this->load->view('Product/Product', $data);


}
}//END CLASS
```

The View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><?php echo $_SESSION['logged_in']?></title>
  <style type="text/css">
  .container {
      width: 15%;
      text-align: center;
      clear:both;
  }
  .container input {
      width: 100%;
      clear: both;
  }
  .logout {
    position: fixed;
     bottom: 10%;
     right: 10%;
  }
  .aboutme{
    position:fixed;
    right:50%;
    bottom:50%;
  }
  .shopbutton{
    position:fixed;
    right:17%;
    top:10%;
  }

  .checkout{
    position:fixed;
    right:10%;
    top:10%;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Logged In As: <?php echo $_SESSION['logged_in']?> </h3>
```

**where the picture is displayed

```
<?php foreach ($profilepicture as $row)
 {
  echo  '<img src='.base_url().'../'.$row->Image_Path.'  style="Height:     300px; Width:200px;"><br>';
} ?>

<form action=" <?php echo base_url().'Profile';?>" method='post'>
  <input type='submit' value='Upload Picture'>
</form>


<div class = 'aboutme'>
<p>About Me</p>
</div>

<div class = 'logout'>
<form action= '<?php echo base_url().'Profile/logout';?>' method='post'>
  <input type="submit" value="Log Out">
</form> 
</div>

  <div class = 'checkout'>
    <form action = '<?php echo base_url().'Cart/display_cart';?>'     method='post'>
    <input type='submit' value='Check Out'>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class = 'shopbutton'>
    <form action = '<?php echo base_url().'Product/display_products';?>'     method='post'>
        <input type='submit' value='Shop'>
        </form>
      </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, try changing the select portion of your query. It should be like:

`$this->db->select('Image_Path, Username');`

if it still not working, try to echo your last query in `get_single_profile()`

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
exit;
```

Comment: with the exit sign it shows nothing but without I see that the last query is only getting the first users picture in the database, when I try to pass the $id variable to the controller it is coming out as NULL. if I pass a specific User_ID say 27, it does show the picture for that user row.

Comment: I figured this line:                                                                                  $this->db->where('User_ID', $id);

Comment: would assign the user id to $id. (I hate commenting here)

Comment: exit sign will terminate the execution of script.

Comment: Therefore, if: echo $this->db->last_query() not showing anything (it should print SQL query which is being executed.) then you are doing something wrong in following statements.                                                                                                           $this->db->select('Image_Path');
   $this->db->from('users');
   $this->db->where('Username', $id);
   $query = $this->db->get();

Answer (score 1):

Changed my Model function to:

```
  public function get_single_profile($id){
   //get whole table


   $this->db->select('Image_Path');
   $this->db->from('users');
   $this->db->where('Username', $id);
   $query = $this->db->get();
   echo $this->db->last_query();
   return $query->result();
```

}//end get_single_profile

And My Controller Index To:

```
public function index()
    {

        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        {
            $data['profilepicture'] =        $this->Profile_Model->get_single_profile($this->session->userdata('logged_in')    );

                $this->load->view('Profile/Profile', $data);
        }// echo session variable logged_in
        else{

            redirect( base_url().'Login');  //redirect to user profile     view after verification)
        }
    }//END Index
```

in the model I changed the Username from the table and set it to $id, In the controller I used a previously defined session variable to set $id to the session...I think